# Is this correct NFA graph?

Tags: finite-automata, formal-languages, nfa

Task: Build NFA from a given regular expression.

I decided to push some of my old programs to GitHub. Specifically problems regarding Theory of formal languages. After testing code I had this result and I can't really tell if this a wrong or correct output. It is kindaaa looks right but not something Thompson's algo would output. Also those little loops look suspicious. They basically do nothing though.
[image: Input example and graph that I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely wrong.

The epsilon-self-loops look to me like a bug in the handling of the union operator. There should be an epsilon transition from each end state in the union to a new end state, so my guess is that you have mixed up the epsilon links. I'm not sure how you end up with the correct epsilon transition on `a` in one case and `b` in the other, so perhaps the bug is more complicated.

You're right that in this case, there is no harm in the epsilon self-loop. But it is quite possible that the absence of an epsilon link from the end of the union leg to the union's end state will cause a problem with `(a*|b)` or `(a|b*)`. One of those might actually turn out to recognize `(a|b)+`.

Also, your Kleene star implementation does not allow zero repetitions. What you have is `(a|b)+`, not `(a|b)*`, because there is no epsilon transition from the start state to the state of the star subconstruction.

Comment: Nah, (a|b*) broke it (( Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

My C# implementation of Brzozowski's algorithm for DFA minimization gives the DFA below. (0) is initial state, (2) and (3) are final states.

[image: DFA for (a|b)*b(a|b)]

Comment: Awesome! Because I have equivalence check somewhere for 2 DFA's) Will covert regex to DFA and run equivalence on converted and your's)

Comment: Did you check it yet?